Android + Kotlin: does a 'Button' declaration cancel the '@Composable' declaration?
The following is a sample project from the Jetpack section of developer.android.com. I have extended it with a function (MyColumnPainter) to allow me to draw the die 'rolling'. The first two calls and the fifth compile just fine. The second two calls give me the '@Composable function must be called from within a @Composable function' error. What is happening, and how to if 'fix' it?
/*
* Copyright (C) 2023 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
package com.example.diceroller

import android.R.drawable
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.diceroller.ui.theme.DiceRollerTheme
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter

val myImageList = intArrayOf(
    R.drawable.dice_1,
    R.drawable.dice_2,
    R.drawable.dice_3,
    R.drawable.dice_4,
    R.drawable.dice_5,
    R.drawable.dice_6
)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DiceRollerTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    DiceRollerApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DiceRollerApp() {
    DiceWithButtonAndImage(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
    )
}

@Composable
fun DiceWithButtonAndImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    MyColumnPainter(result = 1, modifier = Modifier, imageResource = 11)
    var x: Integer // No imagination.
    var xString1: String
    var xString2: String // Also no imigination.
    var xString3: String





    var result by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val imageResource: Int = myImageList[result - 1]

    Column(modifier = modifier, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(imageResource), contentDescription = result.toString())
        MyColumnPainter(result = 1, modifier = Modifier, imageResource = 11)

        Button(
            onClick = {
                MyColumnPainter(result = 1, modifier = Modifier, imageResource = 11)
                for (x in 1..6) {
                    result = (1..6).random()
                    MyColumnPainter(result, modifier, MyImageList[])
                    xString1 = "x = " + x.toString() + " result = " + result.toString()
                    Log.i("FYI", xString1)
                }
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.roll), fontSize = 24.sp)
            MyColumnPainter(result = 1, modifier = Modifier, imageResource = 11)

        }

        }

}


@Composable
fun MyColumnPainter(result: Int, modifier: Modifier, imageResource: Int) {
    Column(modifier = modifier, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
       Image(
            painter = painterResource(imageResource),
            contentDescription = result.toString()
        )
    }

}


onClick is an event listener, not a @Composable. A @Composable describes a UI declaratively, while an event listener is a piece of imperative code run when the event occurs, it has nothing to do with describing UI.

Although composable shares the same programming language and syntax with regular functions, they behave completely differently and serve completely different purpose in completely different context, so should be treated like different languages in your mind and should not be mixed up. As a metaphor, composable is like HTML while regular function is like javascript. onclick is just like an html element triggering an event calling a javascript function, and you wouldn't write html within that javascript function.

Thank you. The obvious follow-up is how to reach a Composable from within an event listener?

Simply don't. Only change the states in event listeners. The state changes will then trigger composable updates.
